# unexpected identifier syntax error in if condition

Tags: php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>REGISTRATION</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>

<?php
 
 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["message"] = "";
 
  
 
 $mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost","root","","accounts");
 
 
 
 
 
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
  $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
  $dday = ($_POST["day"]);
  $indexno = ($_POST["indexno"]);
  
  
  
  
  $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
  $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
  

  
   $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`indexno`, email, name, day) "."VALUES ('$indexno', '$email', '$username', '$dday');";   
  


  
 
  
  
  //check if mysql query is successful
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
{
    $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = "Registration succesful! Added $username to the database!";
    //redirect the user to welcome.php
    header( "location: welcome.php" );
}
  else{
   $_SESSION["message"] = "user could not be added to the database";
  }
  
  
  
 }
 else{
   $_SESSION["message"] = "could not initate seesion";
  }
 
 
 
 ?>



<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/a4e256ed67403c6ad5d43937ed48a77b?family=Core+Sans+N+W01+35+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">
<div class="body-content">
  <div class="module">
    <h1>Create an account</h1>
    <form class="form" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="alert alert-error"></div>
      
      <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" required />
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
      <br>
      
      <input type="text" placeholder="index Number" name="indexno" required /><br>
     
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"  />
     
   
  
                     
<input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php
 $result=mysqli_query("SELECT day=('monday'), COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY day");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   
    
    if(isset($dday) && $dday=='monday') echo 'checked';
    if($data>=8) echo 'disabled'; 
?>
value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>                                

                                                                                           



<input type="radio" name="day" id="frid"  
<?php if (isset($dday) && $dday=="friday") echo "checked";
    ?>
value="friday" required>Friday 02:00 PM - 04:30 PM <br>





<input type="radio" name="day"
<?php if (isset($dday) && $dday=="saturday") echo "checked";?>
value="saturday" required>Saturday 02:00 PM - 04:30 PM <br>






<input type="radio" name="day"
<?php if (isset($dday) && $dday=="sunday") echo "checked";?>
value="sunday" required>Sunday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>
      
     
     
     
     
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

-->

```
<input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php if (isset($dday) && $dday=="monday") echo "checked";
        if($data>=8) echo("function disable() {
   doccument.getElementById("mond").disabled = true;
}")                         ?>
value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>
```

I want this radio button to be disabled if the data variable reaches 8.it says unexpected variable error in the doccument.get..... line please help 
->update
I added the full cod eon top because a  user asked,

I have been struggling with this for quite a long time.
  the purpose of the code is to stop the radio button if it has  been pressed eight time by referencing the data in the data base.so my idea was to put an if condition to disable the radio button in eight turns.

Comment: use `document` instead using `doccument`

Comment: thank you but still it doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer below, you are outputting a function in the middle of an input tag, this is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting javascrupt in the middle of an input tag.

You simply need to echo "disabled", like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php 
    if(isset($dday) && $dday=='monday') echo 'checked';
    if($data>=8) echo 'disabled'; 
?>
value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>
```

Comment: <input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php
 $result=mysqli_query("SELECT day=('monday'), COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY day");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   
    
    if(isset($dday) && $dday=='monday') echo 'checked';
    if($data>=8) echo 'disabled'; 
?>
value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Comment: `mysqli_query($sql,$conn)` two perameter

Comment: You should not be writing your query within the input here. What you are asking in these comments is completely different to what you are asking initially.

Comment: @prem6667777 please check the documentation for `mysqli_query()`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Code this way

add space after `checked` and use ternary for `disabled`

```
<?php
$dday="monday";
$data=9;
?>
<input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php if (isset($dday) && $dday=="monday") {echo "checked ";} 
echo  !empty($data)>=8?"disabled":''?> value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>
```

Comment: the variable data is retreived  from a mysql database

Comment: <input type="radio" name="day" id="mond"  
<?php
 $result=mysqli_query("SELECT day=('monday'), COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY day");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   
    
    if(isset($dday) && $dday=='monday') echo 'checked';
    if($data>=8) echo 'disabled'; 
?>
value="monday" required>Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>

Comment: but why you all code inside `radio`? write query before `radio` and after use this.

Comment: as  in something like this:- $result=mysqli_query("SELECT day=('monday'), COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY day");
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   ???

Comment: and if multiple record in result than what happen?

Comment: I am a beginner so im sorry for the trouble

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: you can put on your question